# How to actually install newer video drivers on manjaro / arch?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, display-driver

As you see below, the closed source driver is 1 year old. Why is this so old? This laptop is not that old, so a newer driver might make a difference.

Also, why is the open source driver, **video-linux** , even older? Isn't that odd? I used it before because it's the only way now to make wayland work. But its age is unsettling.

```
 mhwd -l                                                        1 ✘ 
> 0000:02:00.0 (0200:10ec:8168) Network controller Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  NAME               VERSION          FREEDRIVER           TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         network-r8168            2023.09.12                true            PCI


> 0000:01:00.0 (0300:10de:1f95) Display controller nVidia Corporation:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  NAME               VERSION          FREEDRIVER           TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
video-hybrid-amd-nvidia-prime            2023.03.23               false            PCI
video-hybrid-amd-nvidia-470xx-prime            2023.03.23               false            PCI
          video-nvidia            2023.03.23               false            PCI
    video-nvidia-470xx            2023.03.23               false            PCI
           video-linux            2018.05.04                true            PCI
     video-modesetting            2020.01.13                true            PCI
            video-vesa            2017.03.12                true            PCI


> 0000:05:00.0 (0300:1002:1636) Display controller ATI Technologies Inc:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  NAME               VERSION          FREEDRIVER           TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
video-hybrid-amd-nvidia-prime            2023.03.23               false            PCI
video-hybrid-amd-nvidia-470xx-prime            2023.03.23               false            PCI
           video-linux            2018.05.04                true            PCI
     video-modesetting            2020.01.13                true            PCI
            video-vesa            2017.03.12                true            PCI
```

Comment: If you're running the 470.xxx branch your graphics is almost achieving legacy status. Frequent updates AREN'T expected.

Comment: We cannot say why a closed source driver has not been updated. It is up to the company to produce these.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm not running anything. This is what was detected automatically. A lot of distros use mhwd. Since this is a hybrid graphics machine I'm a bit afraid to go and download drivers from nvidia.

Comment: @music2myear that doesn't make any sense. Nvidia pumps out new drivers all the time.

Comment: I don't know what doesn't make sense: We aren't nVidia. We don't know or control or have a say in how/when/whether nVidia chooses to develop or release drivers. If they have published them, they will be available in the places they publish those. If they have not, they won't be. Linux isn't generally considered a big gaming player and so demand may be a factor here. But, we can only guess at what the answer to your question may be.

Comment: DON'T install from Nvidia's binaries. Manjaro detects your hardware and automatically installs the adequate Nvidia driver version properly packaged for your distro. NO USER INTERVENTION NEEDED (and strongly discouraged). the 470 branch is the Long Term Support driver for legacy hardware, end of story. Literally "end of story" because that's the last version you'll ever use for your graphics and at some point in the near future it'll be dropped completely by Nvidia and won't be updated (note: minor sub-version updates, the "xxx" in 470.xxx) to work with the newer kernel versions.

Comment: @DanielB All mainstream Linux distros have Nvidia drivers packaged in their repositories and provided the OS is updated as it should be any updates are also installed automatically. Indeed, I was under the impression the card was older and you're correct about Nvidia recommending 550.x but Manjaro may need an older version if running an older kernel. Generally speaking one shouldn't mess with this unless one knows exactly why. Not the case here, the question shows the opposite and stating facts is not berating.

Comment: None of your statements make any sense. It would be more logical if the reason is because the hardware configuration is unique and not very popular. And therefore no one bothered to update the pipeline that would give this hardware new drivers.
Saw it before.

Answer (score 1):

The [*nvidia* configuration](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/applications/mhwd-db/-/blob/master/pci/graphic_drivers/nvidia/MHWDCONFIG) just refers to package names. There is no need to update it as new versions of the driver are released. What then prompted the latest change to the *nvidia* configuration? The addition of the *nvidia-390xx-settings*, *nvidia-470xx-settings* and *nvidia-settings* packages to the respective profiles.

What `mwhd` lists is not the version of the driver but the version of the driver *configuration*. Some are very stable and change infrequently, like the *video-linux* configuration. Others change more often.

If you want to know the *actual* version of a driver, you need to check package versions, log messages or accompanying utility programs (like *nvidia-settings*).

Comment: that's odd. I remember back in the day when I updated xorg to the current release, on xubuntu, i got a huge performance boost.
I'll check what you mentioned.